# Profile with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, profile

**UPDATED**

I was working with profile creation for users and authenticating it via devise gem and got stuck on some problem with the default sqlite database and changed to mysql2 so again got an error for running the rake db:migrate

ERROR:

> ```
> 'fsftn@ubuntu:~/pls$ rake db:migrate
> == 20160225174300 CreateProfiles: migrating===================================
> -- create_table(:profiles)
> rake aborted!
> StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: Table 'profiles' already exists: CREATE TABLE `profiles`     (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB/home/fsftn/pls/db/migrate/20160225174300_create_profiles.rb:4:in `change'
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'profiles' already exists: CREATE TABLE `profiles` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
> /home/fsftn/pls/db/migrate/20160225174300_create_profiles.rb:4:in `change'
> Mysql2::Error: Table 'profiles' already exists
> /home/fsftn/pls/db/migrate/20160225174300_create_profiles.rb:4:in `change'
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)'
> ```

---

models/profiles.rb:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profiles_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    profiles_path(resource)
  end
end
```

profiles_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /profiles
  # GET /profiles.json
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
   @attributes = Profile.attribute_names - %w(id user_id created_at updated_at)
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /profiles/1
  # DELETE /profiles/1.json
  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def profile_params
      params.fetch(:profile, {})
    end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :profiles
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  resources :profiles, only: [:edit]
resources :users
root 'posts#index'
end
```

REFERENCE: stackoverflow.com/questions/21976002/ruby-on-rails-4-devise-and-profile-pages

and I scaffolded the profile... any help?? I think its trying to create another profiles table instead of updating... ??

This is how my error on local host looks..

[image: click here for the image]

Comment: paste your code and explain your problem, it's difficult to have an idea without more informations...

Comment: are you talking about creating a page for each user where you can see that information? If so please post your user controller, routes file and any view pages that you have

Comment: have added some of the code sorry was kinda new to stackoverflow didn't know what to add... now its been added cheers!!!